# How to find range of $e^x \sin (x) \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$

Tags: functions

was wondering how to find the range of $e^x \sin (x) \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) $

I do know the range of $\sin x$, which is $-1\leq \sin (x) \leq1$

Hence I should proceed on by multiplying $e^x$ and $\sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$ to both sides?

Thank you.

Comment: For large $x$ this is about the same as $\frac{e^x}{x}\sin x = e^{x-\log x}\sin x$. Note then that the exponent grows without bounds ...

Comment: If there is no restriction on $x$ then it covers all $\mathbb{R}$. Since $e^x$ is unbounded and for $x \ge 1$ we have $0 < \frac{1}{x} \le 1$ and thus $\sin(\frac{1}{x}) \ge 0$ but $-1 \le \sin(x) \le 1$  and thus the range of function is $\mathbb{R}$. also for $x < 0$ we have the similar behavior for $\sin(x) \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$ but $e^x$ diminishes to zero in this region.

Answer (score 0):

The range of $ e^x $ is $ y \in (0, \infty) $

Since the exponential grows faster than the $ \sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ approaches zero

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^x \sin{\frac{1}{x}} = + \infty $$

Multiplying the above by an oscillating $\sin$ function will cause the range to be all reals.

$$ y \in \mathbb{R} $$

Comment: The answer given to me seems to be $0\leq e^x \sin (x) \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)\leq xsin(1/x)$ though, how is this possible?

Comment: Check this inequality with $x=8$

$$e^8\sin{8}\sin{\frac{1}{8}} =~ 2716.92$$
$$8\sin{\frac{1}{8}} =~ .99$$

Comment: Also, feel free to upvote the solution if it is valid.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not understanding how does one come to this answer $0\leq e^x \sin (x) \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)\leq xsin(1/x)$


So from what I understand from your statement if $-1\leq \sin (x) \leq1$ holds true, range of $e^x$ is $y \in (0, \infty)$ , isn't it supposed to be $0\leq e^x \sin (x) \leq \infty $

Comment: You cannot. The inequality is not true or valid.

The range of $e^x$ is $y \in (0,\infty)$. When you multiply this by the sin function, the product will cause the range to be $y \in (-\infty, \infty)$ because $\sin{x}$ will be in the range of $y \in [-1, 1]$